# How do I add a og:url property to all my pages?

Tags: reactjs, react-helmet

This seems like it should be very straightforward, but I'm having trouble making this work.  I want to add a simple tag in the head like

```
import '../src/css/all.scss';
import React, {Suspense} from 'react';
import {Helmet} from "react-helmet";

import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Outlet,
  Navigate,
  useLocation,
  useNavigate
} from "react-router-dom";

import {Row,Col, useTranslation} from './imports';

const baseUrl = process.env.PUBLIC_URL;

function App() {
    return(
        <BrowserRouter basename={baseUrl}>
            <Routes>
                <Route index element={<Navigate to='en'/>} />
                <Route path="/:lang/" element={<Page />}>
                    ...
                </Route>
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}

function Page() {
    const {t} = useTranslation(['globals', 'footer']);

    return (
        <Suspense fallback={<Loader/>}>
            <Helmet>
                <meta charSet="utf-8" />
                <meta property="og:url" content={window.location.host + process.env.PUBLIC_URL + useLocation().pathname} />
                <title>--------</title>
                <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/@google/model-viewer/dist/model-viewer.min.js"></script>
            </Helmet>
            ...
        </Suspense>
    );
}

const Loader = () => (
    <div className="App">
        <img src="./assets/images/logo.png" className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <div>loading...</div>
    </div>
);


export default App;
```

If I just use `window.location.href` for the `currentURL` function, it doesn't update when React Router shifts the URL without refreshing the page.  I'm trying to figure out how to re-render this part without re-rendering my whole app every route change.

Anyone know a simple way to do this?

Comment: As I know, `og:url` is not used in the browser, but by crawlers. So you should not use `window.location.href` to create the `og:url`.

Comment: Are you just trying to set the current `location.pathname` to the `content` attribute? Where is this `Helmet` component rendered within the app? Can you provide a more complete [mcve]?

Comment: @DrewReese I added some more detail from my App.js file

Comment: What is happening when you use the `useLocation` hook from RRD and pass `location.pathname` to the `meta` element?

Comment: Btw this post https://ohdoylerules.com/web/slack-url-meta-data/ might be useful for more OpenGraph —og— metadata